# Running Node.js in Docker container: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, docker, stripe-payments

Overview: I'm trying to run Stripe's simple Node.js integration in a Docker container.  It runs fine as a node app, outside of Docker, but when I start the container, it reports that it cannot find the stripe module.

Dockerfile:
-- My understanding is that "npm ci" should pull all of the necessary dependencies to make this work.  I've tried, separately, running "npm install stripe," which does not change the behavior.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

ARG NODE_VERSION=16.13.1
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine

# Use production node environment by default.
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./src .
RUN npm ci 

USER node

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 4343

# Run the application.
CMD node server.js
```

package.json:
-- I think I'm calling out the Stripe package correctly?

```
{
"name": "node-js-stripe",
"version": "0.2.0",
"description": "A tiny server that connects to Stripe payments",
"main": "server.js",
"scripts": {
  "start": "node server.js"
},
"dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.13.3",
  "stripe": "^14.8.0"
},
"engines": {
  "node": "^16"
},
"author": "Stripe, Mostly"
}
```

server.js (somewhat shortened, left out env variables, etc.):
-- Really the core is just a simple SSL-enabled node app that fetches some stuff from the Stripe server.

```
const express = require('express');
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_KEY_PROD);

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(cors(cors_options));

const YOUR_DOMAIN = process.env.BACKENDURL;

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: [
      {
        price: 'price_1234',
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'subscription',
    success_url: `https://${YOUR_DOMAIN}/success`,
    cancel_url: `https://${YOUR_DOMAIN}/cancel`,
    automatic_tax: {enabled: true},
  });

  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.send(JSON.stringify(session.url));
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Running on port 4242, SSL on 4343'));
https.createServer(options, app).listen(4343);
```

docker-compose.yaml is also super-simple.

```
services:
  server:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - 4343:4343
```

I use

> docker build .

to build the package, then

> docker-compose up

to run it.  That results in:

```
server-1  | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
server-1  |   throw err;
server-1  |   ^
server-1  |
server-1  | Error: Cannot find module 'stripe'
server-1  | Require stack:
server-1  | - /usr/src/app/server.js
server-1  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
server-1  |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
server-1  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
server-1  |     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
server-1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/server.js:5:16)
server-1  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
server-1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
server-1  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
server-1  |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
server-1  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
server-1  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
server-1  |   requireStack: [ '/usr/src/app/server.js' ]
server-1  | }
server-1 exited with code 1
```

All of this seems super-simple to me, like ... There just aren't enough moving parts for the complexity to make it fail.  I'm stumped.  Any hints?

Comment: You likely need to install your modules within the docker container for your script to run using `npm install`

Comment: Ok, so ... because I'm slow: "npm ci" isn't doing that?  Where should I put the "npm install" line?

Comment: That's my bad, `npm ci` should do the same thing. Are you making sure to copy the package.json into the working directory of the application?

Comment: package.json is located in ./src, which (if I understand this correctly) should be getting copied in on the line right above the "npm ci".

Comment: Just added "ls -al" to the Dockerfile, after the copy, it shows that package.json got copied over.  Does it need to be in a /src folder instead?  (Nope, that doesn't help...  Same error.)

Comment: No that part seems fine. Maybe it could be that your program is looking for `STRIPE_KEY_PROD` as an environmental variable but is unable to locate it? That could explain why express is working but stripe isn't.

Comment: Hmm.  I cut out all of the ENVs to try to make the problem statement smaller.  They're all there in the real thing, but I didn't really want to post my Stripe keys.  :-/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it works now.  My computer is the only one who knows why, but, for posterity, here's what I did:

- I had the project in a subfolder that had a docker-compose.yml in the folder above it.  So I moved everything up a folder in the tree.
- Then I consolidated the node's container yaml into the larger yaml.
- It complained about not finding a certificate file, but that was clearly an error in my edits to the yaml, which I quickly corrected.

My guess is that it was, for some reason, using the yaml up a folder instead of the yaml in the current folder, and that was causing some kind of confusion about file locations.  Terrible guess, utterly unsubstantiated, but that's what I've got.  :shrugs: